# Project a specific field from the first element that matches the query condition on the array

Tags: mongodb, projection, embedded-documents, positional-operator

I have a `families` collection. The documents in it have a `users` array. Given this family document:

```
{
    "id" : "1",
    "users" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "2",
            "identities" : [ 
                {
                    "type" : "email",
                    "email" : "foo"
                }, 
                {
                    "type" : "email",
                    "email" : "bar"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "3",
            "identities" : [ 
                {
                    "type" : "email",
                    "email" : "baz"
                }, 
                {
                    "type" : "email",
                    "email" : "qux"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to project the `type` field of the `identities` array elements, but only from the specific user I am querying. The positional operator gets the right user:

```
db.families.findOne(
    { 'users.id': '2' },
    { 'users.$': 1 } 
  )
```

And I can specify the field I'm interested in with:

```
db.families.findOne(
    { 'users.id': '2' },
    { 'users.identities.type': 1 } 
  )
```

But when combining both, only the positional operator is respected:

```
db.families.findOne(
    { 'users.id': '2' },
    { 'users.$': 1, 'users.identities.type': 1 } 
  )
```

(That returns user with id 2, but returns the identities array elements with all fields).
Thought about trying this:

```
db.families.findOne(
    { 'users.id': '2' },
    { 'users.$.identities.type': 1 } 
  )
```

But it's no good since [per the docs](http://MongoDB%20ignores%20the%20part%20of%20the%20path%20that%20follows%20the%20$):

> MongoDB ignores the part of the path that follows the $

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

This will project only the type & users.id  for the selected users.id:

```
 db.families.findOne({"users.id":"2"},{"users":{id:1,"identities.type.$":1}})

 {
"_id" : ObjectId("601f1974cf95940e8e0c814e"),
"users" : [
    {
        "id" : "2",
        "identities" : [
            {
                "type" : "email"
            },
            {
                "type" : "email"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

( Tested in mongod 4.4.3 )
Can be re-written also like this ( also 4.4.3 ):

```
 db.families.findOne({"users.id":"2"},{"users":{id:1,"identities":{"type.$":1}}})
```

Same result in mongod 4.2.12 can be achieved with following aggregation:

```
 db.families.aggregate([  
{$project:{users:{$filter:{input:"$users",as:"us",cond:{$eq:["$$us.id","2"]}}}}}  , 
{$project:{"users.identities.type":1 , "users.id":1  }}     
 ])
```

aggregation explained:

- in first $project stage you filter the array element for users.id:2
- in second $project stage you project only the fields you need

Comment: Thanks, but tested in mongodb 4.2.1 and getting an error for this projection: `">1 field in obj: { id: 1.0, identities: { type.$: 1.0 } }"`

Comment: In 4.4.3 is working perfectly ... :) , maybe time to upgrade ...

Comment: Added to my answer also solution in 4.2.12 but with aggregation framework ...

Answer (score 0):

You only have to use the $ operator to project an  field.

Query:

```
db.collection.find({
  "users.id": "2"
},
{
  "users.identities.type.$": 1
});
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "users": [
      {
        "identities": [
          {
            "type": "email"
          },
          {
            "type": "email"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks, but tested this on mongodb 4.2.1 and it returns the correct user but with all the fields in the identities array elements.

Comment: Have you tried specifies the exclusion of the "email" field? `{
  "users.identities.type.$": 1, "users.identities.email.$": 0 }`